# Excel considering string containing 'E' as exponential value

Tags: excel, excel-2010

My column in excel which is of varchar type contains string of type '0D01234' etc.
For string '0E0000' the excel is formatting to 00.00E+00 integer format. How can i keep the value as it is.

Comment: Format the column as text before you enter the data.

Comment: I have recieved the file from someone else. So I dont enter the data. Do i need to do it manually?

Comment: It's too late then, since the actual cell value will be 0. Do you receive it as an Excel workbook, or a CSV or other format?

Comment: In csv format i have. Can i edit in notepad and copy it to a new excel file? If yes can you guide me how?

Comment: **IMPORT** the file instead of **OPEN**ing it. You will then be able to designate that column as being text when the text import wizard (or Power Query dialog, depending on your Excel version) opens.

Comment: If it's a CSV file, the simplest thing is to rename it as `.txt` then open it from Excel and follow the import wizard. In the last step you can specify that the column is Text.

Comment: Thank you. I am getting the result as expected now